Is it possible to operate on Android devices (tablets or phones) when screen is no longer responsive to touch?
My friend isn't tech-savvy and asked me to save his tablet.
However, the problem is - the screen works but no longer registers touch, so in current state no internal setup can be performed with no input.
Now we are both wondering how to setup the tablet for running e.g. calendar.
We need to somehow connect an external device for input which requires no setup from the tablet.
Is it possible to force mouse connection on the tablet? Is connection to the mouse through the computer feasible?
I know there is Anydesk for remote control of a device, but it needs to be installed on both to work.
Not to mention Android isn't designed for keyboard nor mouse input.
Any advice?
